# Help with tcolorbox package and newtcbinputlisting

Tags: tcolorbox, tcbinputlisting

,I have unsuccessfully been trying to learn how to use the `\newtcbinputlisting` command for some hours now.

I am writing latex in overleaf with a group. We have several .py files we want to input and using minted isn't enough as some of them are more than a page long and therefore with `breaklines=true`, we have the problem where some lines go outside of the bg colorbox.

in our latex repository an example of a file could be:

```
appendix/code/utils/diagnosis_descriptions.py
```

Can someone help me with creating `\newtcbinputlisting{mycode}` command for python? I would like to use the monokai minted style and bg as `\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}`. I simply have not been able to make it input our file and have just met endlessly many errors in my own attempts

link to example overleaf project https://www.overleaf.com/3162436877yfgynkbsrcvr

My code:

```
% IMPORTANT! In order for the document to compile, one needs to use 
XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as compiler. This can be done in  Overleaf by 
Menu -> Settings -> Compiler -> Choose XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry} % Package for pagemargin
\usepackage{setspace} % Package for linespacing
\usepackage{tabularx} % Package for table
\usepackage[skip=10pt plus1pt, indent=20pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=ddmmyyyy]{datetime2}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % Package for creating appendix
\usepackage{minted} % Package for inputting src code
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable}

\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828} % styling for minted

\newtcbinputlisting{\mycode}[2]{  
    listing engine=minted,   
    minted language={python},   
    listing file={#2},  
    %left=5mm,  
    minted style=default,  
    minted options={    
        frame=lines,    
        framesep=1mm,  
        baselinestretch=1,  
        bgcolor=bg,   
        fontsize=\footnotesize,   
        numbers=left,   
        mathescape=true,   
        breaklines=true,    
        breakanywhere=true   
        },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets    
    colback=bg,     
    breakable, % Allows for code to continue on multiple pages   
    listing only,     
}   
\begin{document}

\mycode{appendix/code/utils/diagnosis_descriptions.py}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: yes sorry! I have updated it to contain my code for \newtcbinputlisting{\mycode}

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two and a half problems:

- several missing `,` in your `\newtcbinputlisting`
- if you use `\mycode{diagnosis_descriptions.py}` the macro has one argument, but you defined your macro to have two argument, with the name of the python file as second argument. Either change the definition of your macro or use two arguments when you use it.
- the minted user guide has the following to say about using a background colour:

  > Be aware that if bgcolor is used with breaklines=true, and a line break occurs just before a page break, then text may extend below the colored background in some instances. It is best to use a more advanced framing package in those cases;

  ... given that you are already using a more advanced framing package, setting a minted background colour is not anyway not useful.

---

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry} % Package for pagemargin
\usepackage{setspace} % Package for linespacing
\usepackage{tabularx} % Package for table
\usepackage[skip=10pt plus1pt, indent=20pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=ddmmyyyy]{datetime2}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % Package for creating appendix
\usepackage{minted} % Package for inputting src code
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable}

\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828} % styling for minted

\newtcbinputlisting{\mycode}[1]{  
    listing engine=minted,   
    minted language={python},   
    listing file={#1},  
    %left=5mm,  
    minted style=default, % <- missing   
    minted options={    
        frame=lines,    
        framesep=1mm,  
        baselinestretch=1,  
        bgcolor={},   
        fontsize=\footnotesize,   
        numbers=left,   
        mathescape=true,   
        breaklines=true, % <- missing      
        breakanywhere=true   
        },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets    
    colback=bg,     
    breakable, % Allows for code to continue on multiple pages   
    listing only,     
}   
\begin{document}

\mycode{diagnosis_descriptions.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this made it at least write something now!

However it looks very bad. I have added a link https://www.overleaf.com/3162436877yfgynkbsrcvr to my question, which is an example overleaf project, that shows what minted makes my file look like and what it looks like using tcb.

I would like if the tcb looks like minted but just does the page break correctly. Can you help with that?

Comment: @Mikkel Again missing `,` in your option list and don't set two background colours - it won't get any darker than black

Comment: @Mikkel (I find it very confusing that you added the missing `,` to your question after you got an answer).

Comment: sorry, was copy and pasting and forgot to add missing ,      


I added the comma cause it was something we originally had fixed, but i accidently pasted the version before the comma fix, so i was not meant to be part of the question. We are aware of how to use the commas, just missed some originally, fixed them but used wrong version in here